# Is Star Trek Beyond set after TOS in the original time line?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, timeline, time, star-trek-beyond

*Star Trek (2009)* and *Star Trek Into Darkness* were set before the events of the original series on either timeline.

On the Prime Timeline, TOS lasted for three seasons which I *think* equates to three years.

*Star Trek Beyond* states that they are three years into their mission.

I'm sure that the mission would be vastly different given how events have diverged in the timelines. But in terms of absolute timelines (and personal/ interpersonal development) is Beyond set after the time frame of TOS? I am not sure about how different the start dates of the five year mission where in either time line.

Also is this deliberate? Kirk makes a remark about their lives becoming 'episodic' which makes me think that it is. But it would nice to have this confirmed somewhere.

Comment: We’ve never been super-clear [when The Original Series was set](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12784/what-year-is-star-trek-the-original-series-set-in).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Star Trek Beyond is still set 3 years prior to TOS.

Beyond is set in 2263, while TOS starts in 2266.

From Beyond

> "Captain's Log, Stardate 2263.2. Today is our 966th day in deep space - A little under three years into our five year mission. The more time we spend out here, the harder it is to tell where one day ends and the next one begins.

This image gives a good outline of were the plots diverge.

[image]

[Here is a stardate to standard year conversion chart.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stardate)

Comment: I didn't realise star dates were years now. Seems not very granular.

Comment: @JeremyFrench ah, and update, heres a stardate list http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Stardate  the stardates are always a more weird representation, only in the reboot do they directly match up.

Comment: “TOS starts in 2266” — although [the setting of The Original Series has, historically, been a little fuzzy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12784/what-year-is-star-trek-the-original-series-set-in).

Comment: Typical anti-DS9 chart.

Comment: @brian but but, ds9 is in the chart :(

Comment: It's lower than the other series

Comment: @brian but but... its just betwixt them!